# Отправить трафик с win компьютера через мак

Tags: linux, сеть, mac, nat

Проблема состоит в следующем есть 2 компьютера макбук и стационарный на windows соединенные через роутер в сеть(макс по wifi стационарный по lan) и соотвественно с инетом. Хочется сделать так чтобы без доп софта очень желательно стандартными средствами отправлять весь трафик с windows компьютера на mac а с мака уже это все проксировать в инет. В общем случае я хочу чтобы мак стал альтернативным шлюзом для доступа в интернет. Может кто знает каким образом это можно реализовать буду рад любой помощи. Не обязательно чтобы шлюзом был мак в принципе можно и линукс использовать просто на данный момент имею это.

P.S: мне не нужен прокси нужен именно шлюз чтобы весь трафик в другого компа проходил к примеру через какойто отдельный интерфейс на ноуте

Comment: И что, простым правилом маршрутизации не решается? В Windows по-моему это через `route`: https://www.sysprobs.com/route-add-delete-on-windows-10-static-route А Mac -- Unix, там можно транляцию адресов штатными средствами сделать.

Comment: @0andriy  ну я понятное дело могу напарвить трафик на любой ип в локалке использовав его как шлюз а вот с трансляцией адресов в таком случае проблема выходит я незнаю как это правильно настроить